# How can I fix my button positions on python tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, button, tk-toolkit

I want to fix the position of my two buttons like if I resize my window the buttons will remain in their positions. Or My buttons dynamically resize with the window size. I have positioned my buttons using place. But I ain't getting success. Here's the code so far.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

##wn=turtle.Screen()
wn=tk.Tk()
image=tk.PhotoImage(file="MS-3.PNG")
wn.geometry("700x700")

label1=tk.Label(wn,image=image)
label1.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand="yes")
label1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
label1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
label1.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


def callback1():
    import Detection1

def callback():
    import detection

button1=tk.Button(label1,text="Health Identification", command=callback, bd=12,bg="grey",font="caliber")

button1.place(x=100,y=500 )

label1.image=image
button2=tk.Button(label1,text="Disease Classification", command=callback1, bd=10,bg="grey",font="caliber")

button2.place(x=400, y=500 )

label1.image=image
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadia: If I understood your question correctly, you could make your windows non-resizable with *wn.resizable(False, False)*. Then place your buttons exactly where you want them to be. If you are new to tkinter and python, making every object resizable might be a bit too complex to begin with.

Hopefully this helps.

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

##wn=turtle.Screen()
wn = tk.Tk()
wn.geometry("700x700")
wn.resizable(False, False)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("MS-3.PNG"))

label1 = tk.Label(wn, image=img)
label1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="yes")
# label1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
# label1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# label1.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


def callback1():
    import Detection1


def callback():
    import detection


button1 = tk.Button(label1, text="Health Identification", command=callback, bd=12, bg="grey", font="caliber")
button1.place(x=100, y=500)

button2 = tk.Button(label1, text="Disease Classification", command=callback1, bd=10, bg="grey", font="caliber")
button2.place(x=400, y=500)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks this is actually what I was looking for.